# React Native screen should reload depending on the previous screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm developing a social network, and I have the **Home** screen, where a feed is loaded and a **Post** screen.

How to trigger reloading only when a post is created?

Both screens are inside a Bottom Navigator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you wanna you components to be reloaded with states then you can use redux or react context.
but if you are not using those then you cannot reload but you can call function when tab is changed or pressed refer this https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/#events
and call your functions inside this to reload the data.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('tabPress', (e) => {
// Prevent default behavior
e.preventDefault();

// Do something manually
// ...
});

return unsubscribe;
}, [navigation]);
```

or even you can use focus method

```
React.useEffect(() => {
const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
  // do something
});

return unsubscribe;
```

}, [navigation]);